# Error trying to display data (images and text) from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display images from my database but either I see this message on my browser "item_Details.php?itemID=1" or nothing at all.

I looked everywhere to see What i have done wrong but I can't find anything.

**Here are the tables:**

```
'CREATE TABLE `images` (
`imagesID` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`itemID` int(5) NOT NULL,
`categoryID` int(5) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`size` int(11) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`pix` blob NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`imagesID`),
KEY `categoryID` (`categoryID`),
KEY `images_ibfk_1` (`itemID`),
CONSTRAINT `images_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`itemID`) REFERENCES `items` (`itemID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `images_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`categoryID`) REFERENCES `categories` 
(`categoryID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'

'CREATE TABLE `items` (
`itemID` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`categoryID` int(5) NOT NULL,
`itemName` char(25) NOT NULL,
`item_Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`price` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`contactName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`phone` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`submitDate` date NOT NULL,
`expireDate` date NOT NULL,
`website` char(25) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`itemID`) USING BTREE,
KEY `submitDate` (`submitDate`),
KEY `categoryID` (`categoryID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

Here is the code that I use to display the details about an specific item in a new window:

**classified.php**

```
//Table 3 Electrical Items
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE categoryID='3'";
$result = mysql_query($query3);
//let's get the number of rows in our result so we can use it in a for loop
$numofrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($numofrows == 0){
echo "<p class=spect>Electrical Items:</p><p>No entries yet</p> \n";
}
else{
echo"<table id=mytable cellspacing=0 summary=Items from almacen database>
<caption>Electricals: </caption>";
echo "<TR bgcolor=\"lightblue\"><TH>Item Name</TH><TH>Price</TH><TH>Posted On</TH></TR>\n"; 
for($i = 0; $i < $numofrows; $i++) {
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); //get a row from our result set
$id=$row['itemID'];
if($i % 2) { //this means if there is a remainder
echo "<TR bgcolor=\"#F5FAFA\">\n";
} else { //if there isn't a remainder we will do the else
echo "<TR bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">\n";
} 
echo "<TD><a href='item_Details.php?itemID=<?php=$id; ?>' target = '_blank'>{$row['itemName']}</a></TD>
<TD>&pound;".number_format ($row['price'],2)."</TD><TD>".$row['submitDate']."</TD>\n";
echo "</TR>\n";
} } 
echo "</table><br/>";
```

**item_details.php**

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM images, items WHERE (images.itemID='$id' && items.itemID='$id')";
$result = mysql_query($query1);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
{
header("Content-type: ".$row['type']."");
//header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$row['name']."");
echo"<table>";
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td colspan='2'>
  <h2 style='font-size: large;'> ".$row['itemName']."</h2></td>\n";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo"<td><img border='0' align='right' src='{$row['pix']}' alt='item Image' style='margin-left: 5px;'></td>\n";
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td colspan='2'>
   <div>     
         <b>Price: </b>&pound;" .number_format ($row['price'],2). "<br />
         <b>Posted On: </b>" .$row['submitDate']. "<br />\n
         </div><br>
<b>Description: </b><p>" .$row['item_Description']. "<p><br />
 <div ;='' style=clear: both;>
  <h4 style='font-size: medium;'>Contact details:</h4>
<b>Name: </b>" .$row['contactName']. "<br />
<b>E-mail: </b>".$row['email']." <br /><br />  
</div></td>\n";
echo"</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table><br/>";
```

If I write in classified.php `<a href=item_Details.php?itemID=$id>`, the browser displays "item_Details.php?itemID=1" on the Item_details.php page.

Now if write `<a href='item_Details.php? itemID=<?php=$id;?>` the browser does not display anything at all on the Item_details.php page.

Either way I can't see the pics.

Thank you for your help.
Hernan

Comment: *Way* too much code, at least for my taste. Can you isolate a specific problem? Can you show some relevant parts of the generated HTML (as opposed to the PHP source code)?

Comment: Far too much code and detail.  Summarization is useful.

Comment: I'll take Pekka's and McWafflestix's comments one step farther and say:  *Way* too much spaghetti for my taste.  You may want to look into separating your logic from your presentation.  It would make debugging *far* easier.

Comment: die_r out the results of your queries so you can see if the problem is data or something else

Comment: Can you post the whole HTML source of the output page?  Sometimes there is a mismatched or improperly closed tag that hides most of the content.

Comment: Lots of noise displayed. We normally get paid to debug this kind of lengthy code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid:  `<?php=$id;?>`.

You can use either `<?=$id;?>`, or `<?php echo $id; ?>`.

I prefer the latter as it's more explicit.

**Aside**
I'm not sure if you are working on a legacy application, or if this is new code that you are writing.  If it's new code, you should really spend a day or two (or longer, if you can afford it) looking into some better coding practices.  I would start with separation of logic an presentation.  Try reading this:  <del>http://www.paragoncorporation.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?ArticleID=21</del>

**UPDATE**
Actually, read this, it's better:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617/whats-the-best-way-to-separate-php-code-and-html

Comment: It's still showing this message!! Thanks for the article I should spend at least a week to improve my coding, as you might notice i'm new in php. I'll take your advice. Thanks